# How to hide "Other locations" in Nautilus (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

Hiding bookmarks work by updating ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks but I couldn't find any options for hiding "Other Locations".

Comment: would hiding the Sidebar work for you? Open `Nautilus` click on the hamburger menu (3 parallel lines in the top bar of Nautilus) and uncheck `Show Sidebar`

Comment: @24601 Unfortunately it won't because I need to show other options (media).

Comment: I handle that (media is contained on a NAS on my network) in 20.04 and 22.04 LTS by mounting the share separately in fstab and showing the share on the desktop using the GNOME extension `Desktop Icons (DING)`.